# Can't POST HTML Form Data To PHP Processing Script

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have an HTML form below and I want to post the user inputs to a PHP documents so I can write them to a text file.  The issue I'm running into is getting the file.php script to run.  When I submit the form I'm taken to the correct URL but nothing happens.  The page leaves me with a message saying can't POST to file.php, the PHP script doesn't run and none of the form data seems to be passing.  Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
Name: <input type = 'text' name = "InputName" >
Email:  <input type = 'text' name = "InputEmail" >
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

File.php

```
// Open the text file
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");

 // Write text
 fwrite($f, $_POST["InputName"]);
 fwrite($f, $_POST["InputEmail"]);

 // Close the text file
 fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: Provide the absolute path to `textfile.txt` and make sure you've write permissions.

Comment: What EXACTLY is this message? nothing in your code could possibly generate that, so it must be something else, e.g. apache config

Comment: your file name is File.php or file.php ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see what that throws, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible issues here.

First, you need to make sure that your paths are correct. The handler will look for a file in the same directory as itself with your current `fopen` statement so if the file is not located there it will cause an error.

Next, you are preforming a write function with `fopen` so you need to make sure that the server can write to that file. Usually the server's user is `www` or `www-data` or `apache` or something along those lines. If you're not worried about permission issues you can either set the file's permissions to 775 or 755 and add the file to the www group.

You can also avoid these issues by deleting your existing `textfile.txt` and instead just use the `a+` flag on `fopen`. This flag will create the file if it doesn't exist (with the correct permissions) and if it does exist, it will append the content to the end of the file. Here is the example:

```
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "a+");
```

Lastly, since you are writing to a file directly from user input it might be a good idea to sanitize your input. Also, it might be a good idea to store that file outside of the web root so that it isn't accessible to web users. It may sound a little crazy, but it's better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows always add a *b* to the file opening mode as:

$handle= fopen('file.txt', 'wb'):

Also check if file exists using file_exists() before trying to write to file